# C++ Storing child objects in a common container

Tags: c++, oop

I have a set of abstract parent classes in a namespace, similar to the following

```
namespace Core {
    class Sparse;
    class Dense;
}
```

I define those classes somewhere and after that I derive some child classes:

```
class SparseA: public Core::Sparse;
class SparseB: public Core::Sparse;
class DenseA: public Core::Dense;
```

Now I want to instantiate some objects of the child classes and store them in a common container that can be accessible from anywhere. How can I do this?

And another question: Should I include the child classes in the `Core` namespace aswell?

Thank you.

Comment: do you want to mix both Sparse and Dense in the container? if so, are you sure that's the design you're looking for?

Comment: `boost::variant<std::unique_ptr<Sparse>,std::unique_ptr<Dense>>`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath That could be yet another question. I may or may not need those objects, so I will create them on the fly (in something similar to a Factory for each object) and I will need to access all of them in a Console object, so I thought of storing them all in the same place. Do you have any other design suggestion?

Comment: @MooingDuck using boost is not an option, but thanks anywway :)

Comment: I have no knowledge of the domain, don't know what Console or Dense is and I don't know what you're doing. Suggesting any design would be unwise.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath the Console is a standard Singleton. The rest I think might be irrelevant since this is a completely generic question.

Comment: @manatttta The problem with a completely generic question like this is that the only *real* answer is the completely generic answer "it depends."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long classes `Sparse` and `Dense` are unrelated, you can't store instances of derived classes in the same c++ standard container (unless you're going to use such fancy stuff as `boost::variant` or `boost::any`).

If you give them a common (abstract) base class you can use smart pointers ( e.g. `std::unique_ptr<>` or `std::shared_ptr`) to keep referencing them in a container (using the same pseudo syntax as in your sample)

```
namespace Core {
    class CommonBase;
    class Sparse : public CommonBase;
    class Dense : public CommonBase;
}

typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Core::CommonBase>> MyContainerType;
```

---

Another option might be a template wrapper class solution

```
namespace Core {
    class WrapperBase {
    public:
        // Expose the common interface of Sparse and Dense as
        // pure virtual functions
        virtual void foo() = 0;
        virtual ~WrapperBase() {}            
    };

    template<class Impl>
    class Wrapper : public WrapperBase {
    private:
         Impl& impl_;

    public:
         Wrapper(Impl& impl) : impl_(impl) {}
         void foo() {
             impl.foo(); // Delegate to the actual implementation
         }
    };

    class Sparse;
    class Dense;
}

typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Core::WrapperBase>> MyContainerType;

MyContainerType container;

container.push_back(std::make_unique<Wrapper<SparseA>>());
container.push_back(std::make_unique<Wrapper<SparseB>>());
container.push_back(std::make_unique<Wrapper<DenseA>>());
```

The latter will allow to loosely couple classes like `Sparse` and `Dense` within a single container, but still at least requires some abstract interface, that could be be used behaviorally consistent for both classes, and classes derived from them.

Comment: And is this a good design? or do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @manatttta _"And is this a good design?"_ Well, depends on what you want to solve with it in particular. At least it's working and robust.